# My app is crash when I setValue in firebasedatabase from a BindViewHolder

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app where user can increase their channel subscribers by sub4sub. But problems is that when my countdown timer finished and setting the value in firebasedatabase my app crash. Question is this why my app crash even my codes is working in my another project.

I Try this

```
public void setPlayClick(TextView Times, TextView ActionText, CompaginModel cModel) {
      int count = Integer.valueOf(cModel.times);
      int longvalue = 3000 + count * 1000;
      long countdown = Long.valueOf(longvalue);
      myCount =
          new CountDownTimer(countdown, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              Times.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
              ActionText.setText("Please Wait & Watch the Video");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
              Times.setText("done");
              setViewFinal(cModel);
            }
          }.start();
    }
```

And this

```
public void setViews(CompaginModel cModel) {
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      String savecurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());
      SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
      String savecurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());
      String currentuserid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
          .getReference()
          .child("UsedCompagin/" + "views")
          .child(cModel.userid)
          .child("user_view")
          .child(currentuserid)
          .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
              new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                      //nothing
                  } else {
                    HashMap<String, Object> coinsadd = new HashMap<>();
                    coinsadd.put("currentuser", currentuserid);
                    coinsadd.put("coinsearn", cModel.one_user_cost);
                    coinsadd.put("date", savecurrentDate);
                    coinsadd.put("time", currentTime);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .child("UsedCompagin/" + "views")
                        .child(cModel.userid)
                        .child("user_view")
                        .child(currentuserid)
                     .setValue(coinsadd);
                  }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
              });
    }
```

[image: my app crash log]

Comment: It's hard to say more than what the error message already does: the data you are trying to write contains an array, which Firebase doesn't support. Can you replace te screenshot of the error+stacktrace with its actual text, and include the entire stack trace and then point out exactly what line in your code the error comes from?

Comment: Main error line is  . setValue(coinsadd) ;

Comment: What is the exact line of code that produces that error? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i solved it . The solution was very simple, I had put the time  direct in Hashmap whereas it should have been in string format.

Comment: @AlexMamo my solution is this                 coinsadd. put("time", savecurrentTime) ;

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple, I had put the time direct in Hashmap whereas it should have been in string format.

My Solution is this

```
coinsadd.put("time", savecurrentTime);
```

Comment: @AlexMamo why you edited 